# Outlook 2016 Seeing configuration coding when changing inboxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I just bought a new Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 14, and Office 2016 which includes Outlook 2016.

I've have to different email accounts added.  When I click on one or the other, a page flashes (see the attached pic). I hope you can see the picture through the link.

I appreciate any input.

Thanks,
   Kathy H

[image]

Comment: Can you return the yoga and get another one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP indicates in a comment that the computer was replaced, so there is no longer a problem to solve and the issue cannot be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File, Options.

Under Advanced, Disable Hardware graphics Acceleration

The screenshot is from Outlook 2013, but should be similar enough...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was online chat with Microsoft for an hour.  This was one thing we tried.  It did not work.  So, we removed the account we think is causing it and re-added.  Still did not resolve.  I may have to un-install, and download and activate again.  Any other tips?

Comment: Rev 1 Update: Actually, I tried this again and this time it just flashes solid black, not the screen shot view.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the laptop, return it

Comment: Hi, Got an HP Spectre x360 Convertible - no more problems with Outlook.  But, now cannot download Chrome.  Getting an "Instalation failed due to unspecified error.  If Google Chrome is currently running, please close it and try again."